# Azure function with output to CosmosDB

Tags: azure, function, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the portal to create an HttpTriggered Azure Function that should insert a document in CosmosDB. I use all the defaults and when I configure the binding for output to Cosmos, I use the integration page to specify it..

Ok so my code for the function is:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, out dynamic outputDocument, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    outputDocument = new { Description = name, id = Guid.NewGuid() };

    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
```

and the Function.json is this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "outDatabase",
      "collectionName": "MyCollection",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connectionStringSetting": "johncosmosgorter_DOCUMENTDB",
      "partitionKey": "id",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "cosmosDB"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that the binding parameters where generated by the integration page, I did not write this by hand.

Now when we run the function, we get an 500 error, the logs show this:

```
Cosmos DB connection configuration 'CosmosDB' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
```

This is super strange, since I did not generate the binding. It looks like a version 3 vs version 4 binding parameter conflict, because when I change the binding to have the connectionStringSetting to become connection it actually works and gives me the next error, which is

```
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'databaseId')
```

The binding has a databaseName, changing that to databaseId should not be the solution. Doing that does not work either.

What is wrong here, why is the super simple boilerplate cosmosDB output binding for Azure Functions not working? And why is it so hard to get correct guidance?

Thank in advance for any insight!

John.

Comment: Take a look at this article here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp  For v4 you need to tweak a few setting names. Article for that is here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-cosmos-db-version-3-version-4?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp. btw, i would not create these in the portal. Starting from VS Code is the easiest way to write and test these.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I cannot find or modify the extension settings. So in the portal function, how do I know which version they are using and why do they generate a faulty binding configuration... After changing these in the binding in the function.json, the problem still persists, but then it complains about a databaseId property that is missing. That is not even specified in the article...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Notice that the binding parameters where generated by the integration page, I did not write this by hand. Now when we run the function, we get an 500 error.

Yes, I do agree with you, while creating the cosmos DB output binding using the Integration page, binding parameters are getting generated incorrectly. These parameters are not pointing to v4.

As per [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=python-v2,in-process,nodejs-v4,extensionv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes), **connection** should be used instead of **connectionStringSetting** and **containerName** should replace **collectionName** for v4.

But instead it's generating below attributes-

```
{
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "connectionStringSetting": "afreen-cosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "databaseName": "outDatabase",
      "collectionName": "MyCollection",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "partitionKey": "/id"
    }
```

Even I was getting this `Cosmos DB connection configuration 'CosmosDB' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.` error and got rid of it after correcting **connectionStringSetting** to **connection**.

Then I also started getting `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'databaseId')` error, later I updated **collectionName** to **containerName** and it started working for me.

Final binding attributes looks like below which worked for me-

```
{
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "connection": "afreen-cosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "databaseName": "outDatabase",
      "containerName": "MyCollection",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "partitionKey": "/id"
    }
```

I have got the [output](https://i.imgur.com/HGyo0V5.png).

> how do I know which version they are using

You can check the function's version from [here](https://i.imgur.com/Wqll17d.png).

I have raised a [bug](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2408) with the product team, you can check it for further updates.

Comment: thanks, that worked for me as well, Why does it complain about databaseId when it is referring to the containerName. I know that the concepts are sort-of-related, but this is not really intuitive..

Comment: This is an inbuild issue in v4, so I have raised a bug for the same